# Is it possible to create a application using GTK# and and the .Net Standard Library?

Tags: .net

Is it possible  to create a application using GTK# and and the .Net Standard Library? Or, is the Base Class Library on .Net Framework  All compatible with the Mono's Base Class Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not possible to create a GTK# app using the .Net Standard Library. A better choice is to use the bigger Base Class Library from .Net Framwork or Mono.